# how to travel the multi value of javascript in c# variables dynamicaly

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

heyy... i can create and get value of dynamically created text fields from javascript but i am getting little puzzled to get the multi values of js into my c# coding.. like how can i get values into my C# code and use them into the my C# ..
and when i click on the submit button its passing all the values to the server but i dont know how to get them in my C# coding.

"elemts.html?e0=&e1=&e2=&e3=&e4=&e5=&e6=&e7=&e8=&e9=&e10=&username="

here is the js code kindly help me to get the values into my c# code..??

```
<script>

var f = document.createElement("form");

f.setAttribute("name", "c");


var e = 0;
var t1 = new Array();
for (e = 0; e <= 0; e++) {
    t1[e] = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
    t1[e].setAttribute('type', "text");
    t1[e].setAttribute('name', "e" + e);
    t1[e].setAttribute('onclick', "prt()");

}
var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
s.setAttribute('type', "submit");
s.setAttribute('value', "submit");
s.setAttribute('onclick',"post()");



for (e = 0; e <= 10; e++) {
   f.appendChild(t1[e]);
}

f.appendChild(s);
```

please give me the code that from which i can get values from js into c# easily

thankss in advance

Comment: Are you using the MVC framework?

Comment: visual studio 2010 ... i dont know about MVC framework..??

Comment: can u guide me .?i am ussing simple web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, assuming you are using a WebForms project you should be able to access the dynamic form variables for a  POST method submission using something like the following in your code behind file.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Request.Form != null)
        {
            // Get username value.
            string username = Request.Form["username"];

            // Get the dynamic values and put in a list.
            List<string> dynamicTextValues = new List<string>();
            foreach (var key in Request.Form.Keys)
            {
                if (key.ToString().StartsWith("e"))
                {
                    dynamicTextValues.Add(Request.Form[key.ToString()]);
                }
            }

            // Do what you need to do with your values.

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you assume winform? He's talking about JavaScript and his tags include ASP.NET.

Comment: heeyyy i am getting the values but only of 2 fields e1 and e10 ...what about others ...?:/

Comment: oohhhh i got it .. thankkssssss alotttt love u for that ..:P i just removed your if statement andd it workssssss ..